# Having issues with integrating passport-local with restify

Tags: node.js, passport.js, restify, passport-local

My sample application is as follows

```
var util = require("util")
restify = require("restify"),
    q = require("q"),
    _ = require("lodash");

//Create Server
var server = restify.createServer({
    name: "TestAuth"
});
server.use(restify.queryParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser());

//Initialize Passport
var passport = require("passport"),
    LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

server.use(passport.initialize());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
       return done(null, "Test")
    }));

//Session setup

server.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate("local", function(err, user, info) {
        console.log(util.format("%s is logged in!", user))

        res.send(200);
        return next();
    })(req, res, next);
});

server.listen(8080);
```

When I make the request /login?username=test&password=test it hits the authenticate callback but "user" is false.  When I just use

```
server.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local");
```

I get a Bad Request response from restify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This passport documentation page](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/) shows, in the "Custom Callback" section at the bottom, that, for the way you are using passport in your main snippet, the request method should be a 'get', not a 'post'. I copy here the code snippet from that page:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

That page has other examples of how passport can be used, including the "local" variant that you attempted.

Comment: The reason I'm using a post is because I intend to use the authentication request as a change to generate and store an authentication key.  Other examples have allowed posts which I've tried my best to copy.  I did indeed change it to a get and that worked.  

I am now wondering should the gen of the auth key be tied in with the login or should the client make another trip to the server after getting the login verification and generate and get the auth-key?

Comment: I guess my problem seemed to lie within the Webstorm REST Client.  For some reason it wasn't passing in the request parameters.  If I use postman or fiddler it works fine.