# Node.js, express, passport authentication "Bad Request"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm using Cloud 9 to setup a basic social media website and I am having trouble with registration and authentication of users. I'm using Node.js, express and passport for authentication, and mongoDB as a database.

```
// PASSPORT Setup //

app.use(require("express-session")({
secret: "I am the best",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


// INDEX Page
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
   res.render("landing-page"); 
});


// REGISTER NEW
app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
    res.render("user/register");
});

// REGISTER CREATE
app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    var user = req.body.user;
   var newUser = new User({
       username: user.email,
       firstName: user.firstName,
       lastName: user.lastName,
   });

   User.register(newUser, user.password, function(err, user) {
       if(err) {
           console.log(err);
           return res.render("user/register");
       }
       passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
          res.redirect("/"); 
       });
   });
});

// Login routes
app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
    res.render("login");
});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }) , function(req, res) {

});

// Logout route
app.get("/logout", function(req, res) {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

However whenever I run this, when I sign up a new user, it gives me a webpage with just "Bad Request", however the user is created in the database.

Answer (score -1):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22969874/having-issues-with-integrating-passport-local-with-restify); the bad request is not a problem with your passport method: that indicates the request you try to make is not correct:

- Did you set the head at: `Content-Type: application-json`?
- Also update the `bodyParser` to the last version. This solved a similar problem I had.

Comment: it would be better, if you put meaningful code in the answer, instead of linking to another web page.